# jQuery .find() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, function, internet-explorer, find

I have a function trying to run this:

```
 if ( action=='fadeIn' ) {
  if ( $( this ).css( 'position' ) == "static" ) {
   $( this ).css( {position: 'relative'} );
  }
  $( this ).append( '<span class="bg_fade">' )
 }
 var fader = $( this ).find( '.bg_fade' );

 alert(fader.attr('class'));
```

It works fine in Firefox, but in IE, the alert returns undefined. Any ideas?

The whole code is at http://www.jakelauer.com/jquery/bgFade/jquery.bgFade.js

Being used at jakelauer.com/jquery/bgFade

Comment: Where is the whole code? try the example here:http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Is your conditional block executing in IE? From this code sample we have know way to know what your `action` variable is, what it's for, what sets it, what you're trying to do, etc.

Comment: Here's the whole code: http://www.jakelauer.com/jquery/bgFade/jquery.bgFade.js

Used at http://www.jakelauer.com/jquery/bgFade/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly the fact that IE stops processing on errors somewhere else in the script. Press F12 to bring up developer tools, go to Script, and press Start debugging. Then reload your page. You'll find your error in a hurry.

EDIT:
I took a closer look. Try closing your `<span>` tag in your `append`. The append is not going off in IE.

Comment: Just tried this, no dice. The developer tools window didn't change at all on reload, or when I ran the function. If anybody's interested in testing it themselves, it's at www.jakelauer.com/jquery/bgFade

Comment: Awesome, it was the span tag. Thanks!

Comment: I had an issue where IE would not process `<span></span>` . I had to put a space in it so it looks like `<span> </span>`. Similarly, IE doesn't like it when you put "Heading Tags" (h2,h3,h4,etc.) inside a div.