# JQuery .find() not working in IE for me

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have been struggling with this all day and have tried going through the steps outlined in this [question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2755503/jquery-find-not-working-in-ie) but I can't spot the problem.

I am using the quicktree plugin to display a tree from my unordered list.

If I remove the line

```
<li><a href="#" title="Add a New Page" class="addnewpage-icon addnewpage" id="addnewpageid5">hello<a/>world</li>
```

it works but with the line included it won't.

It's fine in Chrome and FF.

```
<head>

<title>jQuery quickTree plugin example</title> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/tutorials/quickTree/0.4/quickTree.css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 



<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.fn.quickTree = function() {
 return this.each(function(){

 //set variables
 var $tree = $(this);
 var $roots = $tree.find('li');

 //set last list-item as variable (to allow different background graphic to be applied)
 $tree.find('li:last-child').addClass('last');

 //add class to allow styling
 $tree.addClass('tree');

 //hide all lists inside of main list by default
 $tree.find('ul').hide();

 //iterate through all list items
 $roots.each(function(){

 //if list-item contains a child list
 if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
    //add expand/contract control
    $(this).addClass('root').prepend('<span class="expand" />');
 }


 }); //end .each

 //handle clicking on expand/contract control
 $('span.expand').toggle(
 //if it's clicked once, find all child lists and expand
 function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('contract').nextAll('ul').slideDown();
 },
 //if it's clicked again, find all child lists and contract
 function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('contract').nextAll('ul').slideUp();
 }
 );
 });
};

</script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.quickTree').quickTree();
}); 
</script> 

</head> 
<body> 



<ul id="0" class="quickTree"> 
<li id="currentId4"><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> 
    <ul id="4"> 
<li><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> one</li>
<li><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> two</li>
<li><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> nmnmnm</li>
<li><a href="editpage/5">home</a> aaaaa</li>
<li><a href="editpage/4" class="show-always">hello<a/>world</li>
<li><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> nmnmnm</li>
<li><a href="#" title="Add a New Page" class="addnewpage-icon addnewpage" id="addnewpageid5">hello<a/>world</li>
</ul> 
    </li> 
    <li id="currentId5"><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">where</a>
    <ul id="4"> 
<li><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> one</li>
<li><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> two</li>
<li><a href="editpage/5" class="show-always">home</a> hghghgh</li>
</ul>  
</li> 
<li><a>nmnmnmnm&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a/></li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `<a/>` to `</a>`

Comment: Ha ha, I've been staring for so long I couldn't see the wood for the trees! Can't accept you answer yet due to the new feature. Thanks!

Comment: @Here Be Wolves - the one that pops up a dialogue that counts down the amount of time until you can accept an answer. First time I have seen it.

Comment: Heh, can happen to anyone. Glad to be able to help :P